# Filtering rows based on multiple condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table

| id_employee | stat | kind_sco | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | h | 1 | 93 |
| 123 | h | 2 | 76 |
| 123 | h | 3 | 12 |
| 123 | h | 4 | 91 |
| 456 | m | 1 | 64 |
| 456 | m | 2 | 60 |
| 456 | m | 3 | 56 |
| 456 | m | 4 | 90 |
| 789 | l | 1 | 90 |
| 789 | l | 2 | 76 |
| 789 | l | 3 | 89 |
| 789 | l | 4 | 45 |

And I want to filter the rows based on this condition

```
groupby(['id_employee', 'stat']) -> 
if stat == h:  take row with 'kind_sco' == 3 
elif stat == m:  take row with 'kind_sco' == 1 
else: take row with 'kind_sco' == 2
```

My current solution is like this

```
data[(data['stat']=='l') & (data['kind_sco']==2) |
   (data['stat']=='m') & (data['kind_sco']==1) |
   (data['stat']=='h') & (data['kind_sco']==3)]
```

so the expected output is like

| id_employee | stat | kind_sco | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | h | 3 | 12 |
| 456 | m | 1 | 64 |
| 789 | l | 2 | 76 |

But it will not effective if the condition is more complicated

What is the simpler solution? I already think to use groupby and filter() but dont know how to tweak it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is "wrong" with your current solution? You can dynamically generate your "complicated" condition. If there are no statistics involved and the rules are this simple, not convinced why not going the way you already did. For large datasets, `apply` will kill your performance.

Comment: @deponovo i feel like it not effective especially if the condition is more complicated, and cluttered. Ah i see, i will consider it. Thank you for the information

Answer (score 1):

Here the key is to use `apply` function, which passes each grouped data frame so that you can "apply" your logic to it (here filtering) and then return that data

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {"id_employee": "123", "stat": "h", "kind_sco": "1", "score": "93"},
    {"id_employee": "123", "stat": "h", "kind_sco": "2", "score": "76"},
    {"id_employee": "123", "stat": "h", "kind_sco": "3", "score": "12"},
    {"id_employee": "123", "stat": "h", "kind_sco": "4", "score": "91"},
    {"id_employee": "456", "stat": "m", "kind_sco": "1", "score": "64"},
    {"id_employee": "456", "stat": "m", "kind_sco": "2", "score": "60"},
    {"id_employee": "456", "stat": "m", "kind_sco": "3", "score": "56"},
    {"id_employee": "456", "stat": "m", "kind_sco": "4", "score": "90"},
    {"id_employee": "789", "stat": "l", "kind_sco": "1", "score": "90"},
    {"id_employee": "789", "stat": "l", "kind_sco": "2", "score": "76"},
    {"id_employee": "789", "stat": "l", "kind_sco": "3", "score": "89"},
    {"id_employee": "789", "stat": "l", "kind_sco": "4", "score": "45"},
]


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["kind_sco"] = df["kind_sco"].astype(int)  # convert to int for comparision

grouped = df.groupby(["id_employee", "stat"])


def filter_rows_in_each_group(d: pd.DataFrame):
    if (d["stat"] == "h").all():
        return d[d["kind_sco"] == 3]
    elif (d["stat"] == "m").all():
        return d[d["kind_sco"] == 1]
    else:
        return d[d["kind_sco"] == 2]


filtered_data = grouped.apply(filter_rows_in_each_group).reset_index(drop=True)
print(filtered_data)
```

The output is as expected

```
  id_employee stat  kind_sco score
0         123    h         3    12
1         456    m         1    64
2         789    l         2    76
```

Comment: This one works! thank you tbhxor

Comment: Glad to know. Would you mark this answer as solved and also upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make smth up with a *mapper* and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) ?

```
mapper = {
    "l": data["kind_sco"].eq(2),
    "m": data["kind_sco"].eq(1),
    "h": data["kind_sco"].eq(3)
    # add here more groups/conditions ..
}

out = (
    data.groupby(["id_employee", "stat"], group_keys=False)
        .apply(lambda g: g.loc[mapper.get(g.name[1])])
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   id_employee stat  kind_sco  score
2          123    h         3     12
4          456    m         1     64
9          789    l         2     76
```

Comment: **NB**: IMO, the *mapper* would make more sense if you construct pairs of id/stat and make them as keys `(123, "h"): data["kind_sco"].eq(2)..`